# Replaced DVD ROM with DVD RW, but new drive is not detected

Tags: windows-xp, dvd

I have replaced the DVD-ROM drive in my computer with a DVD Writer but Windows will not detect the new drive.

I have not installed any new software except a firmware update for the new drive.

Windows seems to think that I still have the original drive fitted.

Comment: Please don't place your personal email address here as part of your question. Solutions and suggestions will be posted here on this page.

Comment: What happens when you put a blank CD or DVD in the drive?